# Variant implementation like boost::any with auto-conversion support

Tags: c++, variant

I want to implement a variant class that can store any datatype (like boost::any) but with the support of datatype conversion. For example,

```
Variant v1(int(23)); can be converted to bool via v1.get<bool>()
using Conv<int, bool>, Variant v2(CustomT1()); to CustomT2
via Conv<CustomT1, CustomT2> and so on.
```

Here is the current implementation, based on the idea of boost::any:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename Src, typename Dest>
struct Conv
{
    /* static? */ Dest convert(const Src& src) const { throw std::runtime_error("type cast not supported"); }
};

template<> struct Conv<int, bool>
{
    bool convert(const int &src) const { return src > 0; } 
};

class IStoredVariant
{};

template<typename T>
struct variant_storage : public IStoredVariant
{
    variant_storage(const T& value) : m_value(value)
    {}

    T&       getValue(void)       { return this->m_value; }
    const T& getValue(void) const { return this->m_value; }

    template<typename U>
    U make_conversion(void) const // just an idea...
    {
        return Conv<U, T>().convert(this->getValue());
    }
protected:
    T m_value;
};

class Variant
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Variant(const T& value) : m_storage(new variant_storage<T>(value))
    {}

    IStoredVariant&       getImpl(void)       { return *this->m_storage; }
    const IStoredVariant& getImpl(void) const { return *this->m_storage; }

    std::auto_ptr<IStoredVariant> m_storage;

    template<typename T>
    T get(void) const
    {
        const IStoredVariant &var = this->getImpl();
        // ????????????
        // How to perform conversion?
    }

    template<typename T>
    void set(const T &value)
    {
        this->m_storage.reset(new variant_storage<T>(value));
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Variant v(int(23));
    bool i = v.get<bool>();
}
```

From the get<> template method, I only have access to an IStoredVariant pointer, but I need to know the concrete type to choose the Converter<>. Is there any design pattern or workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to use `boost::variant` as the basis, since that will remember which type is contained. This information is essential ;v) .

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. You would need to have support for templates in virtual functions to make this happen.

In the *calling* context, you only have the type to be converted to, and you can't retrieve the stored type. In the *called* context, you only have the stored type and can't retrieve the type to be converted to.

There is no way to pass the type between them, so you can never know both types at once and therefore cannot perform any conversion.

Comment: Templated virtual functions… there's a C++2x feature. Give the ABI designers a nosebleed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: don't you just need introspection + a JIT ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is intractable.

If you have lost type information, then you cannot recover it (not fully) because the language itself does not support it (no reflexion/introspection).

You can still know the exact type, but you cannot get properties such as conversions to arbitrary types, because conversions mechanisms are baked in at compile-time (depending on constructors, conversion operators and language rules).

If you have only a small subset of types that you are interested in, then `Boost.Variant` is your best bet.

If you really wanted to have a fully dynamic language... then either ditch C++ or reimplement a dynamic language on top of C++...

Comment: The type is not lost. I just need a way to pass the requested destination type T to the concrete IStoredVariant implementation.

Comment: @cytrinox: That would require virtual templates, which do not exist in C++.

Comment: @cytrinox: it *is* lost. A type only exists during compilation in C++, because there is no reflexion/introspection. Afterwards, all you have is a pointer to the `typeinfo` structure, which definitely not as powerful.

Comment: @cytrinox: What you are doing is called *type erasure* where "erasure" is there because the real *type* of the object contained is *removed* from the container. Of course the object still has a concrete type, you cannot really remove that, but when you get an `any`, you don't really *know* what is contained in there. At runtime the type stored in the object is *unknown* (i.e. a function that receives a `boost::any` and forwards it to a different function does not *know* what the `any` holds, only that it can manage it through the common `any` interface)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `typeid` operator to get the type information of the type stored in the variant and compare this to the `typeid` of the `T` in `get`:

Extend the `IStoredVariant` with this interface definition:

```
class IStoredVariant
{
    ...
    type_info getTypeId() = 0; // note the abstract definition
    ...
}
```

Add the implementation to the concrete variant storage:

```
template<typename T>
struct variant_storage : public IStoredVariant
{
    ...
    type_info getTypeId() { return typeid(T); }
    ...
}
```

Use it in the Variant class:

```
class Variant
{
    ...
    template<typename T>
    T get(void) const
    {
        const IStoredVariant *var = this->getImpl();
        if(typeid(T) == var->getTypeId())
        {
            // type matches: cast to the type
            variant_storage<T>* my_typed_var = static_cast<variant_storage<T>* >(var);
            // do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** You can also look at the [property implementation of OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/group__Property.html) which does not use `typeid` but enums for a specific set of types. All other types are therefore unsupported.

Comment: Well, you have missed the "else" part. For conversion, T and typeid are always different.

Comment: I do not compare `T` with `typeid`, I compare two `type_info` objects. If they match, the types must be the same.

Comment: Yeah, but they are never the same, e.g. T=int requested but internal variant_storage<bool> is stored.

Comment: So? whats the problem? I thought this was the whole idea behind the variants to have implementations of different types, or was it not?
Or is your question this: what happens if the types mismatch? Well, there are multiple options, for example throwing an exception or using out values.

Comment: get<> should convert the stored value to the requested type T using Converter<OriginType, T>. But your code example only returns a value if the requested type T and the internal value are the same type.

Comment: This is just `dynamic_cast`, but worse, and it doesn't solve the OP's problem.